# chrome extension popup cannot find element by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I know similar questions have been asked many times, but I didn't find a solution for mine yet. My question is really simple. All I want to do is to test actions on popup.html, for here, I have a click button on popup, when I click it, I want to show alert. But nothing happened. It's not finding the element. I don't understand what's going wrong here.

**manefest.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "test",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/*",
    "notifications"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id='btn'>click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$('#btn').click(function (){
   alert("test");
};
```

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code executes as soon as `<script>` tag is read, i.e. before your element exists in DOM.

Wrap it in `$(document).ready()` and you're good to go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* your code */
});
```

For a non-jQuery solution, wrap it in `DOMContentLoaded` listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  /* your code */
});
```

Finally, you can simply move the `<script>` tag to the end of `<body>`, but it's a less robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your popup.js syntax is wrong

```
  $('#btn').click(function (){
   alert("test"); 
};
```

should be

```
    $('#btn').click(function (){
   alert("test");
   });
```

looks like you are missing a paran;